# Meta privilege says site switcher is on the left

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange-button, privileges-page

If you look at the privilege "participate in meta" on any site ([example](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta)) you'll see this (emphasis added):

> The link [to meta] also appears in the Stack Exchange site switcher (**top left** in the header) and under the "help" menu (top right in the header).

This is no longer the case, at least on the regular site.

This should be changed, although I'm not sure what to recommend it be changed to, given that the site switcher is still on the left for mobile web. (And to further confuse things, the help menu it talks about is only visible for users who have no access to review queues, even though many of them would have like to have had the help link anyway.)

Comment: Maybe just "top right (or top left for mobile)" should work

Comment: Yeah, that probably needs a rewrite

Comment: The obvious resolution here is to move the switcher to align with the help text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has been fixed meanwhile:

> #### Where is meta?
>
> There is a link to meta in the Stack Exchange site switcher (top right in the header).

Judging by [this Wayback Machine snapshot](https://web.archive.org/web/20180706133045/https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta) within 6-8 months of the bug report or maybe even sooner.

<sub>(Note that in [mobile-web](/questions/tagged/mobile-web) mode the site switcher is still located top left, but that mode is (almost) deprecated.)</sub>

Comment: It will be deprecated in the next 6-8 years ;)